# Make grails conditionally select an item in a combo box

Tags: grails, gsp

```
<g:select name="division.id"
    from="${divisionInstance}"
    value="${name}" 
    optionKey="id"
    optionValue="${{"${it}"}}"
    noSelection="['':'Please select']"
    required="" />
```

What I want to happen, if

```
divisionInstance.id == personInstance.divisionId
```

then select that item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work like this

```
<g:select name="division.id"
    from="${divisionInstance}"
    value="${personInstance.divisionId}" 
    optionKey="id"
    optionValue="${{"${it}"}}"
    noSelection="['':'Please select']"
    required="" />
```

It is similar to the last example in the documentation of the `select` tag: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html

```
<g:select optionKey="id" value="${favoriteBook.id}"
    name="book" from="${bookList}" />
```

> In this case, value should contain the ID of favouriteBook rather than the book object itself because optionKey is set to the id property.

So in your case you have a list of divisions that gets iterated through and your `optionKey` is set to `id`. The entry whose `value` evaluates to true gets selected. If `value` is set to `${personInstance.divisionId}` the condition for the selection is:

```
divisionInstance.id == personInstance.divisionId
```

Comment: that's exactly right, thanks! I would give you a +1 but there is a 15 rep point requirement

Answer (score 0):

well this is maybe not following DRY but it´s as simple as

```
<g:if test="${divisionInstance.id == personInstance.divisionId }>
<g:select name="division.id"
    from="${divisionInstance}"
    value="${personInstance.divisionId}" 
    optionKey="id"
    optionValue="${{"${it}"}}"
    noSelection="['':'Please select']"
    required="" />
</g:if>
<g:else>
<g:select name="division.id"
    from="${divisionInstance}"
    value="${name}" 
    optionKey="id"
    optionValue="${{"${it}"}}"
    noSelection="['':'Please select']"
    required="" />
</g:else>
```

i do wonder if it is not possible to do like :

```
<g:select name="division.id"
    from="${divisionInstance}"
    value="${if(divisionInstance.id == personInstance.divisionId){return personInstance.divisionId}else{return name}}" 
    optionKey="id"
    optionValue="${{"${it}"}}"
    noSelection="['':'Please select']"
    required="" />
```

but i cant test it at the moment